# How does sleep cmd in python works?

Tags: python

In one file, `test1.py`, I am calling function of another file, `test2.py`.

**test1.py**

```
def attente_evenements(self):
            self.checkLog.evnt_findLogIdentity()
            print "\t\t\t SHOULD HAVE GOT THE LOG FILE \n"
```

**test2.py**

```
def evnt_findLogIdentity(self):
            sleep(180)
            print "\t\tLogging in is done \n "
```

I should get the order of print statements as

1. Logging in is done
2. SHOULD HAVE GOT THE LOG FILE

But WHY i am getting in reverse ORDER

1. SHOULD HAVE GOT THE LOG FILE
2. Logging in is done

??????

Comment: The call to sleep is irrelevant. Try removing it; you should get the exact same thing.

Comment: This should work fine, there must be something else wrong with your code

Comment: i need to print "Logging in is done" after 3 min , for which i think i need to sleep ?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger code behaves as if it was multithreaded right now

Comment: Where does the `sleep` function comes from, exactly?

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger ,  from time import sleep ,

Comment: I don't get the same result with two simple functions and a call to `time.sleep()`, so there's something else in the parts of the code you didn't post.

Comment: self.checkLog = MonitorLog(theData,self.cbCheckLog) 

where monitorlog is the class in test2.py where evnt_findLogIdentity is defined .

Answer (score -1):

As per the [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.

Since there is no thread to suspend, you should be getting an Reference error for `_select`.

Comment: But here , during sleep(180) in evnt_findLogIdentity , its printing SHOULD HAVE GOT THE LOG FILE

Comment: @Akshay clarified my own understanding of time.sleep, please see update.

Comment: When it suspends the execution of this thread , will it continue the current thread execution ?

Comment: if so how can i not suspend but just wait for 3 min here ?